# Как перезапросить форму отправки?

Tags: php

Как в данном случае перезапросить форму отправки, чтобы при обновлении страницы не было сообщения "Подтвердите повторную отправку формы".
`mywebforyou.webutu.com`

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['test']) and !isset($_POST['q'])) {
        $q = 0; // номер текущего вопроса
        $title = 'Testing';
    } 
    else {
        // Создаем сессионную переменную test, содержащую массив ответов
        if ($_POST['q'] != '1') {
            // если номер вопроса не один (если пришел не первый раз)
            $_SESSION['test'][] = $_POST['answer']; // сессионная переменная 'test' - это массив, в который прилетают ответы пользователя
        }
        $q = $_POST['q'];         // в переменную прилетает номер вопроса (<input type="hidden" name="q" ...>)
        $title = $_POST['title']; // имя поля ввода в форме (<input type="hidden" name="title"...>)
    }    
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>English checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="clearfix">
        <h1>English checker‎</h1>
        <h2><?=$title?></h2>
        <?php
            switch ($q) {
              case '0': include 'start.php'; break;
              case '1': include 'questions/q1.php'; break;
              case '2': include 'questions/q2.php'; break;
              case '3': include 'questions/q3.php'; break;
              case '4': include 'questions/q4.php'; break;
              case '5': include 'questions/q5.php'; break;
              case '6': include 'questions/q6.php'; break;
              case '7': include 'questions/q7.php'; break;
              case '8': include 'questions/q8.php'; break;
              case '9': include 'questions/q9.php'; break;
              case '10': include 'questions/q10.php'; break;
              case '11': include 'questions/q11.php'; break;
              case '12': include 'questions/q12.php'; break;
              case '13': include 'questions/q13.php'; break;
              case '14': include 'questions/q14.php'; break;
              case '15': include 'questions/q15.php'; break;
              case '16': include 'questions/q16.php'; break;
              case '17': include 'questions/q17.php'; break;
              case '18': include 'questions/q18.php'; break;
              case '19': include 'questions/q19.php'; break;
              case '20': include 'questions/q20.php'; break;

              default:
                include 'result.php';
            }
          ?>
          <footer>
             <p class="mp">
                 <a href="index.php">Restart the test</a>
             </p>
          </footer>
     </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы имеете ввиду сброс POST данных?

Comment: https://myrusakov.ru/php-resubmit.html

Comment: @Александр Жариченко в нужное место пропишите `die(header('Location: ?'));`

Comment: Можно весь switch заменить на более простой и более логичный такой код:

`if ($q == 0) include 'start.php';
elseif ($q >= 1 && $q <= 20) include "questions/q$q.php";
else include 'result.php';`